# binary tree method

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BST{
public:
  int n,*v,vn;
  struct node {
    int val;
    node *left,*right;
    node (int v){ val=v; left=right=0;}
    void Print(node *p){
       cout<<p->val;

       if (p->left){
           Print(p->left);
       }
       else if(p->right){
           Print(p->right);
       }
    }
  };  node *root;

  node *rinsert(node *p,int t){
     if (p==0){
        p=new node(t);
        n++;
     }
     else if (t<p->val){
        p->left=rinsert(p->left,t);
     }
     else if (t>p->val){
        p->right=rinsert(p->right,t);
     }

     return p;
  }
  void traverse(node *p){

    if (p==0) return;
    traverse(p->left);
    v[vn++]=p->val;
    traverse(p->right);
  }
  void print(){
    Print(root);
  }

public:
   BST(int maxelms,int maxval){
       root=0;
       n=0;
   }
   int size(){
      return n;
   }
   void insert(int v){
       root=rinsert(root,v);
   }
   void report(int *x){
       v=x;
       vn=0;
       traverse(root);
   }
};
int main(){
  BST bt(12,25);
  bt.insert(12);
  bt.insert(10);
  bt.insert(25);
  bt.insert(7);
  bt.insert(11);
  bt.insert(8);
  bt.insert(4);
  bt.insert(3);
  bt.insert(20);
  bt.insert(23);
  bt.insert(24);
  bt.insert(1);

  return 0;
}
```

The compiler says that `Print()` is undefined. Why? I have declared it inside class.

Comment: I think in the function "print" the function "Print" can't be accessed without giving the structure name.

Comment: If you have a compiler error message you don't understand, **put the whole error message into your question** (and indicate the line it complains about in your source code).

Answer (score 0):

move your "void Print(node *p)" function outside the struct node definition

Answer (score 0):

**void Print(node *p){** --> **static void Print(node *p){**

**else if(p->right){** --> **if(p->right){**

**Print(root);** --> **node::Print(root);**

Answer (score 0):

You have two print methods:

```
BST::node::Print(node* p);
BST::print();
```

Capital `Print` is part of the `node` struct.  Lowercase `print` is part of the `BST` class.

Problems you may encounter:

- calling `print` outside the class.  You would need to call: `BST bt; bt.print();`
- calling `Print` outside the `node` class.  You would need to call `node n; n.Print(&n);`  Which would be somewhat silly.  There's no need for `Print` to be part of the `node` class if it takes in a `node`.
- calling `Print()` -- there's no such thing.  There's `print()` and `Print(node*)` -- capitalization matters.

If that doesn't answer your question, please update your question with more information.  Copy and paste the actual compiler error, and indicate which line gives you the error.

Comment: @user466534, then post your error message, and indicate the problem line.  Otherwise we can't help you.